# How do I make this into a Pascal's triangle instead of a Right triangle?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, pascals-triangle

I need a code for making a *Pascal's triangle*. This code is for a *Right triangle*, but I need it to be a *Pascal's triangle*. It needs to have 10 rows and does have a gap in the middle of the Top and the Bottom.
Can anyone please help me on this? `for` loops will be fine.

```java
public static int get_pascal(int row, int col) {
    if (col == 0 || col == row) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return get_pascal(row - 1, col - 1) + get_pascal(row - 1, col);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //row size variable
    int rowNum = 5;

    levels = new String[rowNum];

    int i = 0;
    int arIndex = 0;
    System.out.println(recurseRow(i, rowNum, arIndex));
    System.out.println("                                 ");
    System.out.println(upsideDown(rowNum - 1));
}

//Recursion for row
public static String recurseRow(int i, int rowNum, int arrayIndex) {
    if (i == rowNum)
        return "";
    else {
        int k = 0;
        int next = i + 1;
        String str = recurseCol(i, k);
        levels[arrayIndex] = str;
        arrayIndex += 1;
        return str + "\n" + recurseRow(next, rowNum, arrayIndex);
    }
}

//Recursion for column
public static String recurseCol(int i, int k) {
    if (k > i)
        return "";
    else {
        int next = k + 1;
        return get_pascal(i, k) + " " + recurseCol(i, next);
    }
}

//upside down recursion
public static String upsideDown(int index) {
    if (index < 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        String str = levels[index];
        index -= 1;
        return str + "\n" + upsideDown(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Pascal's triangle* - is a triangular array of *binomial coefficients* where the elements of the first row and column are equal to one, and all other elements are the sum of the previous element in the row and column.

```
T[i][j] = T[i][j-1] + T[i-1][j];
```

You can create an *iterative* method to populate such an array:

```java
public static int[][] pascalsTriangle(int n) {
    // an array of 'n' rows
    int[][] arr = new int[n][];
    // iterate over the rows of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // a row of 'n-i' elements
        arr[i] = new int[n - i];
        // iterate over the elements of the row
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
                // elements of the first row
                // and column are equal to one
                arr[i][j] = 1;
            } else {
                // all other elements are the sum of the
                // previous element in the row and column
                arr[i][j] = arr[i][j - 1] + arr[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;
    System.out.println("n = " + n);
    System.out.println("Pascal's triangle:");
    int[][] arr = pascalsTriangle(n);
    for (int[] row : arr) {
        for (int element : row)
            System.out.printf("%2d ", element);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
n = 10
Pascal's triangle:
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 
 1  4 10 20 35 56 84 
 1  5 15 35 70 126 
 1  6 21 56 126 
 1  7 28 84 
 1  8 36 
 1  9 
 1
```

---

<sup>See also: [Array of binomial coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209905/14940971)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can add prefix of multiple spaces where you recursively create a row: instead of

```java
String str = recurseCol(i, k);
```

you'll have

```java
String str = "";
for (int spaces = 0; spaces < 2 * (rowNum - i - 1); spaces++) { 
  str += " ";
}
str += recurseCol(i, k);
```

You also need to format all numbers to have the same width inside recurseCol, for example now all numbers will be 3 digits wide:

```java
return String.format("%3d %s", get_pascal(i, k), recurseCol(i, next));
```

The resulting code of the modified methods:

```java
//Recursion for row
public static String recurseRow(int i, int rowNum, int arrayIndex) {
    if( i == rowNum)
        return "";
    else {
        int k = 0;
        int next = i + 1;
  String str = "";
  for (int spaces = 0; spaces < 2 * (rowNum - i - 1); spaces++) {
      str += " ";
  }
        str += recurseCol(i, k);
        levels[arrayIndex] = str;
        arrayIndex += 1;
        return  str + "\n" + recurseRow(next, rowNum, arrayIndex);
    }
}

//Recursion for column
public static String recurseCol(int i, int k) {
    if(k > i)
        return "";
    else {
        int next = k + 1;
        return String.format("%3d %s", get_pascal(i, k), recurseCol(i, next));
    }
}
```

The "magic" numbers 2 and 3 are related to each other: if each number is `n`-digits wide, then we need to add a prefix to the string consisting of `n-1` spaces repeated `rowNum - i - 1` times.

There are other methods to achieve these, but I think that the above allows to get the result with minimum modifications.